# putClientProperty("SideComponent",...) does not work

Tags: codenameone

I have been using the following code to add a CheckBox as a side menu item (see below). But after I update my CodenameOne, Eclipse, and Java versions, this code does not work anymore (side menu does not show the checkbox with label "CheckBox", instead it shows a default side menu item with label "Command").

Should I use a different method to add a component to side menu?

```
public class SideMenuCheck extends Form{

 public SideMenuCheck (){
    Toolbar myToolbar=new Toolbar();
    setToolbar(myToolbar);
    Command sideMenuItemCmd = new Command("Command");
    CheckBox sideMenuChkBox = new CheckBox("CheckBox");
    sideMenuItemCmd.putClientProperty("SideComponent",sideMenuChkBox);
    myToolbar.addCommandToSideMenu(sideMenuItemCmd);
    show();
    }
}
```

I have also tried adding a button instead of a check box as side menu item, but this code also failed to show the button on the side menu...

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That approach for adding a component to the side menu has been deprecated for a while. You should use the API `addComponentToSideMenu` instead.

The reason this stopped working for you is the switch from the underlying `SideMenuBar` implementation to the [new on-top implementation](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/pixel-perfect-on-top-menu.html) a while back.